# .NET Entity Frame work / Model Inheritence

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have started using Entity framework and it works great. I have decided to create inheritance models such as this....

```
public class tlkpCafe : EntityAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int CafeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cafe { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Facebook { get; set; }
    [Url]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string URL { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

So the Cafe has a seperate class 'Entity Address' containing the full address, postcode etc..

This is perfect. However Ef decides to use a seperate table to acomplish this. It will map the 'Entity Address' with a extra 'Discriminator' column to determine which table the address belongs to.

My question is, is it possible to store as a flat table, so everything still in 'tlkpCafe'?

I assume the fluent API have some kind of mapping instruction to do this I have not been able to find the code that might accomplish this.

Comment: Check [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) for some information on the Table-Per-Concrete-Type inheritance strategy. However, I'm not sure inheritance is the right strategy here. What would be wrong with a separate table for addresses and an AddressId foreign key?

Comment: No nothing and from a purest database angle this is definitely cleaner.  But id like to keep the tables simple where possible - also it would be slightly smaller . Looking at the article perhaps something like ` modelBuilder.Entity<EntityAddress>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("tlkpCafe");
        });'?

Comment: I would caution you against this inheritance pattern in general.  It seems to violate the general rule that inheritance should be an "is a" vs a "has a" relationship.  Not that you can't go this way if you *really* want to, but be very sure about the consequences down the road.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your EntityAddress class is just a set of fields you want to include in some entities more than a entity inheritance hierarchy.

So I would split the answer in two:

1. if my assumption is true, then if you don't map the class EntityAddress to the DbContext (don't declare any DbSet nor any configuration for this entity), then EF won't create any separate table for this class but just will add those fields to the tlkpCafe table. This is because you are not declaring any hierarchy and DbContext doesn't know about EntityAddress class.
2. if you really want an entity hierarchy, then you should have a look to Table per Type (TPT) vs Table per Hierarchy (TPH) configuration [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4). What you are looking for is TPH, but consider that you will get a single table for all entities that inherit from EntityAddress